# How to integrate $12x^3(3x^4+4)^4 $ in a nice way

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I antidifferentiate $12x^3(3x^4+4)^4 dx$ ?

I guess it is possible to multiply it all out, and then do term by term, but is there a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, there's a nice way - the key point is to notice that $12x^3$ is the derivative of $3x^4$. Hence we can let $u=3x^4+4$ and victory ensues:

$$\int 12x^3(3x^4+4)^4\, dx=\int u^4\,du=\frac{u^5}{5}+C=\frac{(3x^4+4)^5}{5}+C$$

Comment: Ok thanks. We just started learning U substitution

Comment: @Hello Oh okay.  Can you fill in the details of this then, or would you like some more explanation on the u substitution part?

Comment: No, that is sufficient. I did not realize that U substitution was the way to do it.

Comment: This is a type of integral that it would be helpful to spot: $\int f'(x)f(x)^n=\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$.